# Read command line ENVs in `bash -c`

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I'm using some shell script to download my tool from public network(CDN or S3), while some user's host not connected to public network, we have to add a proxy to help them.

The install shell seem like this:

```sh
HTTPS_PROXY=1.2.3.4:4321 bash -c "$(curl -L https//url.com/install.sh)"
```

while the sub-command `curl -L` still need the proxing, we have to make it like this:

```sh
HTTPS_PROXY=1.2.3.4:4321 bash -c "$(curl -x 1.2.3.4:4321 -L https//url.com/install.sh)"
```

> For curl, `-x` means proxy flag.

the proxied-install script seem ugly, is it possible to passing the outter `HTTPS_PROXY=1.2.3.4:4321` to inner `curl`? I've tried this:

```sh
# set proxy ENV for current session
exprot HTTPS_PROXY=1.2.3.4:4321; bash -c "$(curl -L https//url.com/install.sh)"
```

This seems ok, but for security reason, it pollute current session with a `HTTPS_PROXY` env, sometimes may not acceptable for sensitive users.

Comment: Why is the curl command even within a `bash -c` in the first place?

Comment: @BenjaminW. Download then run the bash. `-c` means commands read from the string.

Comment: Oh, right - you could use something like `HTTPS_PROXY=1.2.3.4:4321 curl -L https//url.com/install.sh | bash` instead. Or, for various reasons, `HTTPS_PROXY=1.2.3.4:4321 curl -L https//url.com/install.sh > install.sh; ./install.sh` (avoids trying to execute partially downloaded file, lets you inspect the file before executing etc.)

Comment: @BenjaminW. The 1st failed, the ENV seems not passed to next bash after pipe; the 2st still the same problem, the ENV not passed to the second command `./install.sh`.

Comment: If you need it also when running `install.sh` (wasn't aware of that), you can use your second attempt, but put in parentheses so it runs in a subshell and doesn't affect the parent environment: `(export HTTPS_PROXY=1.2.3.4:4321; bash -c "$(curl -L https//url.com/install.sh)")`